# Fedora workstation 27 freezes after login

Tags: linux, fedora, reboot, freeze, bios

I am using Asus zenbook pro ux501vw and have recently successfully installed fedora 27 and then shut down with it. When I restarted it for the very first time, I typed in my password and it went to a screen with a logo of some sort in white and a blackish background and froze there.
I have 2 graphics cards
SSD Storage
Name anything and I will tell you but please do give me your assistance.
Thank you very much your your time.

Answer (score 1):

I have this freeze issue after upgrade Fedora from 25 to 26. Then I upgrade Fedora from 26 to 27,  it still same issue. **[UPDATE]** **It also happened on Ubuntu 17.04 upgraded to Ubuntu 17.10 by `do-release-upgrade` in my another Dell laptop. Remove EasyScreenCast works but still <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+FN</kbd> are freeze and no solution yet.**

I tried `sudo dnf update --refresh --best --allowerasing` but seems no effect. Then I change login gear icon option from "Gnome" to "Gnome on Xorg", it doesn't freeze.

Eventually I able to choose "Gnome" without freeze by removed [EasyScreenCast extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/690/easyscreencast/) directory located in `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` , refer to [this answer](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/114455/fedora-26-gnome-shell-doesnt-come-up-after-login-from-gdm/?answer=114915#post-id-114915). Note that you don't have to remove other extensions. You can login with "Gnome on Xorg" to remove it if <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+FN</kbd> not working.

Comment: Interestingly for me, `Gnome on Xorg` option is the one that freezes, and `Gnome` works just fine :(